# ros indigo installation error on raspberry pi 2

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi. In part 4.3 while Building the catkin Workspace i get this error

```
Linking CXX shared library /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/collada_parser/lib/libcollada_parser.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcollada-dom2.4-dp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/build.make:125: recipe for target '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/collada_parser/lib/libcollada_parser.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/collada_parser/lib/libcollada_parser.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:91: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'collada_parser':
  Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', '-j2']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

i followed the path and didn't find `libcollada_parser.so so` wht am i missing and how to overcome that problem ?
i'm new to ROS and just getting started
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230101/ros-indigo-installation-error-on-raspberry-pi-2/) by [ahmedfanni](https://answers.ros.org/users/26388/ahmedfanni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Escontrela](https://answers.ros.org/users/29812/escontrela/) on 2017-03-24**:
Could you please post how you installed the missing files. Im having the same error and i havent been able to find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the error, some files my mate didn't install, so i had to format  and restart the whole process and now it's working just fine

---

Originally posted by [ahmedfanni](https://answers.ros.org/users/26388/ahmedfanni/) with karma: 26 on 2016-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-25**:
Please just accept your own answer instead of closing the question.

**Comment by [ahmedfanni](https://answers.ros.org/users/26388/ahmedfanni/) on 2016-03-25**:
i just signed up so i dont have enough points to do that :) but i dont get wht's wrong with closing the question ? isn't that normal when u find the right answer ? iam new here so i still dont know how things work here

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-25**:\

> but i dont get wht's wrong with closing the question ? isn't that normal when u find the right answer ?

It's not 'wrong', but we typically don't do that here on ROS Answers. It's not a forum.

To indicate something is answered, we tick the checkmark next to the answer.